# siblings within a table in Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, parent, children, siblings

I'm having a hard time trying to get this to work.

Here's my html layout

```
<td class="subpages-cell">
<span class="subpages-posts-image">
    <a href="">
         <figure class="tint t7">
             <img src="" class="subpages-image">
         </figure>
    </a>
</span>
<p class="subpages-text">
    <a href="">Hello</a>
</p>
</td>
```

I want the "subpages-text" class to be hidden and when the used hovers over the "subpages-image" class I want it to show. 
I've tried multiple ways using css and .hove Jquery but can't get to target the right one.

As of now i fixed it by using:

```
p.subpages-text { display:none;}

.subpages-cell:hover p.subpages-text a {display:block;}
```

but since the td has a padding then the area where you hover extends over the image.

This is my first post and I tried to do as much research as I could. Please let me know if I broke any rules.
Cheers

Comment: I think your TD should have the subpages-cell class.

Comment: afaik css selectors will not work backwards, you may need to use javascript for this

Comment: also - why are you hiding the main container of the element you want to 'hover' over?

Comment: You are right @dystroy, thanks. I wrote the wrong class for the TD.

Comment: @BarryChapman, thanks, I figured it wouldn't, hopefully javascript will do the trick. I'm hiding it because I only want to show multiple rows/columns of my posts' thumbnails and then when you hover you get the name of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should give your `p` a different class than the `td` that it is in, otherwise your css rule will hide the container too (which will hide everything in it as well).

Then you can use jQuery to find the `p.subpages-text` that is nearest the `img` that you hover over.

To do that you could write something like this:

```
$('.subpages-image').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).closest("span").siblings(".subpages-text").show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).closest("span").siblings(".subpages-text").hide();
    }
);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aj87N/3/

Comment: Hi @jake Zeits, didn't get this too work yesterday but I'm trying it right now

Comment: @JUPAGO let me know what problems you run into

Comment: Zeits IT WORKEDDD! I figured out why, I had the .subpapges-text as a block so the mouse wasn't hovering over the childen img. A couple of CSS lines of code for img, p, and a and it worked! Boss plans to release site in a month or so, will post link then. Cheers!!! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for

```
$('.subpages-image').hover(
function(){
  $('.subpages-text a').show();
},
function(){
  $('.subpages-text a').hide();
}
);
```

JS fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/Aj87N/

Comment: Thanks @Raghu! I'll give it a try, it sucks that I can't post the page  since it's under "coming soon" but will be sure to follow up!

Comment: This fix seems to be working the best, the issue I'm having is that I have multiple columns and it triggers every single .suppages-text class. any idea? how to fix it?

Comment: @juapago . what you can do is , if your page is supporting html5 then use the data property to assign ID to each of the column . Something like <p class="subpages-text" data-column-id="1">. And then use this $(.subpages-text a).data("1).hide. I have not tried this in jsfiddle but little tweak will help you get over.

Answer (score 0):

As the element with which you want to interact is nested below the sibling of the element you want to reveal/hide based on the interaction, this can't be done with CSS (though JavaScript is an option, of course); however if you move the interaction to the `span` element that's a sibling of the `p` element, this is possible (though it's not *quite* what you wanted, I know):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="subpages-text">
                <span class="subpages-posts-image">
                    <a href="">
                         <figure class="tint t7">
                             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife" class="subpages-image" />
                         </figure>
                    </a>
                </span>

                <p class="subpages-text"><a href="">Hello</a>

                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the following CSS will work:

```
.subpages-text p.subpages-text {
    display: none;
}

.subpages-text:hover span:hover + p.subpages-text {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pt5y7/1/).

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas, I see what you mean... the span bothers me but since I'm pulling the content through php for a wordpress plugin I did not want to mess too much with it. But the use of + is an interesting idea, I haven't tried it before.